# Block regex to recognize number while it's part of a URL

Tags: c#, regex, url, phone-number

I am using regex: `[(]?(((\d)([() .-]+)?)+){7,18}|\*\d{3,10}|\d{3,10}\*(?!/)`

How can I change the attached regex to not recognize the numbers that are part of a URL to the Facebook as phone number, but could recognize a phone number that is not part of a URL?

The URL:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Fashion-24/151055822249094?fr=ts

The above regex detect "151055822249094" as phone number.

Comment: Again, a question with history. Could you let us know what language you are using? Perhaps, you can as well use `(?<![/\d])(?:[(]?(?:(?:(?:\d)([() .-]+)?)+){7,18}|\*\d{3,10}(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\d{3,10}\*)(?!/)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookbehind in your regex:

```
(?<!/)[(]?(((\d)([() .-]+)?)+){7,18}|*\d{3,10}|\d{3,10}*(?!/)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C#, you can use the look-behind to make sure you are not inside the URL:

```
(?i)(?<!\bhttp\S*)(?:[(]?(?:(?:(?:\d)([() .-]+)?)+){7,18}|\*\d{3,10}(?!\d)|(?<!\d)\d{3,10}\*)(?!/)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3Fi)(%3F%3C!%5Cbhttp%5CS*)(%3F%3A%5B(%5D%3F(%3F%3A(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5Cd)(%5B()%20.-%5D%2B)%3F)%2B)%7B7%2C18%7D%7C%5C*%5Cd%7B3%2C10%7D(%3F!%5Cd)%7C(%3F%3C!%5Cd)%5Cd%7B3%2C10%7D%5C*)(%3F!%2F)&i=Phone%20is%20151055822249094%2C%20see%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FFashion-24%2F151055822249094%3Ffr%3Dts)

Comment: Glad it did. Then, please consider accepting (since it worked for you) and upvoting (if proved helpful to you) the answer.